# JackHenry | Silverlake | Fetch Credit Cards with account number

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

In **Silverlake**, I want to fetch all the credit cards associated with an account number. Is there any provided operation to do so?

I have checked **Credit Card Account Search** https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/card-services/crcardacctsrch/

Here you can search credit cards with last name, phone number or state code, but not account number.

For ETF cards, we have the operation to search with account id https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/card-services/eftcardsrch/ . I am looking for same for credit cards.

**Long story short, I have an account number and I want to fetch all credit cards associated with that. How to do so? This is my main query.**

Also, if someone can provide example lastName/phoneNumber for which I will get good response. I have tried few but getting '404 Not Found'. I have even tried with "where last name contains 'a'" but still same response.

I am trying on test environment of Silverlake

URL: https://jxdmz.Jackhenry.com/jxchange/2008/ServiceGatewa/CrCard.svc
Operation: CrCardAcctSrch
Query: Where lastName contains 'a'

Expectation: Getting some response
Getting: 404

Answer (score 0):

The CrCardAcctSrch operation can only be used search via the following elements -

1. LastName
2. Phone Num
3. PhoneType
4. StateCode

You will want to look at the [CrCardAcctInq](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/card-services/crcardacctinq/) operation to find the card for a specific account. The FAQ section for CrCardAcctInq has more info on how to search, here's the copy/paste -

> Q: Where do I get the CrCardAcctId information so I can use
> CrCardAcctInq?
>
> A: If you are looking for credit card numbers to use in our DMZ test
> environment just let us know and we will provide a test account for
> you. Otherwise, if you’re asking in general where to get CrCardAcctId,
> those are stored in the core products and are only available in the
> AcctSrch response with CC as account type in the  element.
> To maintain the highest of security standards, JHA employs a secured
> Card Data Environment(CDE) to store a cards PAN (Primary Account
> Number). Representation of card PAN’s outside of the CDE are tokenized
> values, so those are the values returned in the AcctSrch
> response. A masked value of the card will also be available in the
> response. You will use the token value for all subsequent CrCard*
> message requests.

Also you're running into a second problem with the JX URL that you're pointed at. That URL for the DMZ instance you're using will always be https://jxdmz.jackhenry.com/jxchange/2008/ServiceGateway/ServiceGateway.svc. The hostname might change depending on which environment you're in, but the format will always be the same for JX service gateway integrations. Changing that URL will result in the 404 error that you're running into.